# Jekyll undefined method `yaml_file?' in GitHub Actions

Tags: github-actions, jekyll

I am running a custom Jekyll Docker image with the Jekyll-Pandoc plugin to build a website on GitHub pages. It runs just fine on my local machine and used to work on GitHub as well, but recently when I call the same image through GitHub Actions I have been getting the following error:

```
Jekyll Feed: Generating feed for posts
                    ------------------------------------------------
      Jekyll 4.3.2   Please append `--trace` to the `build` command 
                     for any additional information or backtrace. 
                    ------------------------------------------------
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/forwardable.rb:233:in `yaml_file?': undefined method `yaml_file?' for #<Jekyll::Page @relative_path="index.md"> (NoMethodError)
```

The whole log is [here](https://github.com/p3palazzo/TAU0005/actions/runs/4475184606/jobs/7864365301?pr=140#step:3:213) and the offending `index.md` file is [there](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/p3palazzo/TAU0005/refactor/index.md).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug in Jekyll.

Please report this at Jekyll's GH repo (https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll) highlighting the following:

- `excerpt:` provided in `index.md` front matter expected to be rendered instead of Jekyll extracting an excerpt from body content.
- `Jekyll::Page` doesn't respond to a method `yaml_file?` (delegated by `Jekyll::PageExcerpt`).

(*Would be super helpful if you can provide a minimal reproducible repository which the maintainers will clone to test at their end.* But if you don't have the time, provide the GH repo you have mentioned in this stackoverflow ticket.)

Comment: Thanks @ashmaroli. Upon further inspection it seems the conflict on my setup is between jekyll-relative-links v0.7.0 and the way the Minimal-Mistakes theme handles the `excerpt:` field in YAML frontmatter. Downgrading to jekyll-relative-links v0.6.1 fixed it, but I will need to try with the default theme to see what happens.

Comment: Update: the exception can be reproduced with any file that contains a YAML field named `excerpt:`. I filed a bug report here: <https://github.com/benbalter/jekyll-relative-links/issues/91>